# How to add a course overview video?

Tags: php, moodle

I am using Moodle 3.1+. I want to add a course overview video in my course. I know we can add a video as related media in lesson. Similarly can we add a video to the course?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your course settings you can upload a video to be shown to non-enrolled users for that course.

1. As course admin, choose your course and go to Course administration->Edit settings;
2. In "Course summary" click the icon "insert Moodle media", choose and upload your video.
3. Save

Now, if you go into your list of courses (/course/index.php), you should see, along the description of your course, an embedded video.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand.

Comment: I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: How can I get the location of uploaded file using code?

Comment: Without knowing other specifications, I would say you can use the Moodle File API: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API